# PHP Traits conflict (trait param)

Tags: php

I have three traits.

Trait `Param`, `GroupId` and `SessionId`. Traits `GroupId` and `SessionId` include `Param`.

Class `GroupSession` include traits `GroupId` and `SessionId`

```
<?php

trait Param
{
    private $params = [];

    public function setParams($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function getParam($param)
    {
        return isset($this->params[$param])
            ? $this->params[$param]
            : null;
    }
}

trait GroupId
{
    use Param;

    public function getGroupId()
    {
        return $this->getParam('group.id');
    }
}

trait SessionId
{
    use Param;

    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $this->getParam('session.id');
    }
}

class GroupSession
{
    use GroupId {
        GroupId::setParams insteadOf SessionId;
        GroupId::getParam insteadOf SessionId;
    }
    use SessionId;
}

$t = new GroupSession();
```

When I try to run this code I get an error:

`GroupId and SessionId define the same property ($params) in the composition of GroupSession. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible.`

Tell me, please, how to resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Would be easier if `GroupSession` imported `Param` instead of `GroupId`/`SessionId` doing so. The latter two traits just expect the importing class to provide a getParam/setParam method. Since `GroupSession` in your implementation has to take care of/modify the traits anyway, I don't think that's a disadvantage.

Comment: @VolkerK, thank you! Now my problem is solved by this way. But I think, that is not native method. Why? Because our traits needs to implemetation some methods in classes, that include its.

Answer (score 2):

Resolves to method naming conflict

```php
trait A
{
    public function smallTalk()
    {
        echo "I am form trait A and method smallTalk";
        echo "<br>";
    }

    public function bigTalk()
    {
        echo "I am form trait A and method bigTalk";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}


trait B
{
    public function smallTalk()
    {
        echo "I am form trait B and method smallTalk";
        echo "<br>";
    }

    public function bigTalk()
    {
        echo "I am form trait B and method bigTalk";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

class AB
{
    use A, B {
    A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    B::bigTalk as gazi;
    B::smallTalk insteadof A;
    A::smallTalk as anis;
    }
}

$obj1 = new AB;
$obj1->bigTalk();
$obj1->gazi();
$obj1->smallTalk();
$obj1->anis();
```